# Modifying the path parameters using interceptor (Spring mvc)

Tags: spring, interceptor

I have a requirement of checking a condition and modifying the path parameters before the request goes to the controller. 
One way of doing it is using filters. But i need to wire dependencies, which is not possible in a filter. (can be done in the old school was of initializing app context and picking the bean from it)
Here is what i have done
. Created an interceptor, and in the prehandle forwarded to

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception {
if (condition ) {      
request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()).forward(request, 
response);
return true;
}

return false;
```

i get this error:

SEVERE: Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER

Any idea what could be wrong ?

thanks ,

Comment: You can autowire in a filter, see https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/delegating-filter-proxy.html, (this is not the crappy "old-school" way you refer to)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on spring, why don't you use AOP? You can use 'before' advice.

Comment: aspectj is not in the pom, thinking it might be an overhead to add it just for this